# Screenshot of a distant Desktop on the same network

Tags: powershell, screenshot, monitoring, rdp, administration

I'm a newbie new employee at an IT firm as a system information administrator and my boss gave me the project of: taking a screenshot of a distant machine in the network without notifying them.
They should not get disconnected from their session as well.
I'm looking for any 3d party software (free or otherwise) or any powershell script to help me through this.
My progress:

---

PowerShell Script for saving a screenshot locally:

```
$Path = "C:\Users\Naskez\Desktop\Screenshots"
If (!(test-path $path)) {
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $path
}
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$screen = [System.Windows.Forms.Screen]::PrimaryScreen.Bounds

$image = New-Object System.Drawing.Bitmap($screen.Width, $screen.Height)

$graphic = [System.Drawing.Graphics]::FromImage($image)
$point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(0, 0)
$graphic.CopyFromScreen($point, $point, $image.Size);
$cursorBounds = New-Object System.Drawing.Rectangle([System.Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Position, [System.Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Current.Size)

[System.Windows.Forms.Cursors]::Default.Draw($graphic, $cursorBounds)
$screen_file = "$Path\" + $env:computername + "_" + $env:username + "_" + "$((get-date).tostring('yyyy.MM.dd-HH.mm.ss')).png"

$image.Save($screen_file, [System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat]::Png)
```

Afterwards, If you want to get a desktop screenshot from an RDS server (or a desktop Windows, in which multiple concurrent RDP connections are allowed), you must first get a user session ID on the remote computer. Specify the name of a remote computer/server and a user account in the following PowerShell script:

```
$ComputerName = "nld-rds1"
$RDUserName = "h.jansen"
$quser = (((query user /server:$ComputerName) -replace '^>', '') -replace '\s{2,}', ',' | ConvertFrom-Csv)
$usersess=$quser | where {$_.USERNAME -like $RDUserName -and $_.STATE -eq "Active"}
$usersessID=$usersess.ID
```

Then finally excecuting a Psexec with the right sessionID :

```
.\PsExec.exe -s -i $usersessID \\$ComputerName powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -WindowStyle Hidden -file "\\nld-fs01\Screen\CaptureLocalScreen.ps1"
```

---

Problem is: my company does not allow multiple RDP connections. So if i try to do this i have to disconnect them.

Any solutions or tip will be much appreciated.

NB:The PowerShell solution listed above is not mine. Original link below:
http://woshub.com/take-user-desktop-screenshot-with-powershell/

Comment: _"taking a screenshot of a distant machine in the network without notifying them"_ sounds very illegal to me because it is spying on logged on users. You should tell your boss you cannot accept such an assignment.

Comment: we're litterally the ISS team and we're monitoring user traffic and activity. How is that illegal?

Comment: So you really think spying on users is legal? What country is that?